# How to save Image captured from camera in gallery as well as in backup folder

Tags: image, android-camera

In My application I am capturing image from camera and storing it in folder created by me. This folder is getting created in Pictures. Now I wants to save same image in my  local storages's /BackUp folder.

This is code for

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    // Activity request codes
    private static final int CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE = 100;
    private static final int CAMERA_CAPTURE_VIDEO_REQUEST_CODE = 200;
    public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE = 1;
    public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO = 2;
    private MultipartEntity multipartEntity;
    // directory name to store captured images and videos
    private static final String IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME = "FORMS";
    private Bitmap bitmap1;

    private Uri fileUri; // file url to store image/video
    private static String output;
    private ImageView imgPreview;
    private VideoView videoPreview;
    private Button btnCapturePicture, btnRecordVideo;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        imgPreview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgPreview);
        videoPreview = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoPreview);
        btnCapturePicture = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCapturePicture);
        btnRecordVideo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRecordVideo);

        /*
         * Capture image button click event
         */
        btnCapturePicture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // capture picture
                captureImage();
            }
        });

private void captureImage() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

        fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);

        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);

        // start the image capture Intent
        startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE);
    }

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // if the result is capturing Image
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                // successfully captured the image
                // display it in image view
                previewCapturedImage();
            } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                // user cancelled Image capture
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "User cancelled image capture", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            } else {
                // failed to capture image
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Sorry! Failed to capture image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
        }

private void previewCapturedImage() {
        try {


            imgPreview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileUri.getPath(),
                    options);
imgPreview.setImageBitmap(bitmap1);


            //imgPreview.setImageBitmap(result);
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

public Uri getOutputMediaFileUri(int type) {
        return Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile(type));
    }
    private static File getOutputMediaFile(int type) {

        // External sdcard location
        File mediaStorageDir = new File(
                Environment
                        .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
                IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME);

        // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
        if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
            if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
                Log.d(IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME, "Oops! Failed create "
                        + IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME + " directory");
                return null;
            }
        }

        // Create a media file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss",
                Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
        File mediaFile;
        if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE) {
            mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator
                    + "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".jpg");
        }

        return mediaFile;
    }
```

Right Now this image is getting save at PICTURES/FORMS Folder. I wants to save it to FORMSBACKUP/IMAGES Folder as well.